# How to get Nearest lower value?

Tags: nearest

`Nearest`gives me the closest value to my reference, but what if I am always looking for the closest value, which is lower than my reference?

```
list = {0.2, 0.25, 0.32, 0.36, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.63, 0.70, 
0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.25, 1.30, 1.40, 1.50, 1.60, 1.80, 2.00, 
2.20, 2.50, 2.80, 3.00, 3.20, 3.60, 4.00, 4.50, 5.00, 5.50, 6.30, 
7.00, 8.00};

ref = 3.902;

result = Nearest[list, ref][[1]]

4.
```

...as in the example above: how I tell Mathematica that I need the 3.6 value instead of 4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the elements greater than the reference out of consideration, by, for example, `DeleteCases`:

```
Nearest[DeleteCases[list, x_ /; x > ref], ref]
```

or `Cases`:

```
Nearest[Cases[list, x_ /; x < ref], ref]
```

or for any 1D list of numbers like in your case (I assume, `list` might also be unsorted)

```
Last@Sort@Select[list, # < ref &]
```

or simply replace `Nearest` with `Max` and apply to the list where numbers above `ref` have been dropped

```
Max@Select[list, # < ref &]
```

or several other ways which don't yet come to my mind.

Comment: This seems a bit inefficient on large lists given that it creates a new copy.

Comment: @lirtosiast It's going to be O(n) complexity in any case, most likely will use O(n) memory regardless of implementation too.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use a custom distance function with a penalty:

```
Nearest[list, 3.902, DistanceFunction -> (Abs[#1 - #2] + 100 Boole[#1 < #2] &)]
   {3.6}
```