# Optimize cost when ordering wood boards (cutting stock problem)

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

That is probably a common optimization problem, but I don't know how to solve it efficiently.

Say you want to buy the following wood boards: 2 to 1m, 3 of 1.5m, 2 of 2m. The shop has the following boards: 1m @ 10€, 2m @ 15€, 3m @ 19€.

What boards should you buy to minimize you cost (cutting boards is free)?

The following brute-force approach works in that case, but it is very inelegant:

```
(* shop specifications*)
lengthPriceAssociation = {1 -> 10, 2 -> 15, 3 -> 19} // N;

(* your desired boards *)
targets = {1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2};

(* define all possible combinations *)
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
comb = SetPartitions[targets]
(* {{{1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2}}, {{1}, {1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2}}, ... *)

(* select combinations that do not exceed max length available in shop *)
feasable = Select[comb, 
  Max[Total /@ #] <= Max@lengthPriceAssociation[[All, 1]] &]

(* sum the lengths of each combination *)
potentialOrdersRaw = Sort /@ Map[Total, feasable, {2}]

(* round up to existing lengths [credits to \
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97520/18767] *)
potentialOrders = 
 Flatten[Nearest[{1, 2, 3}, #, 
     DistanceFunction -> (Abs[#1 - #2] + 100 Boole[#2 < #1] &)] & /@ 
   potentialOrdersRaw, {3}];
 (* {{{2, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 3, 3}, ... *)

 (* compute cost of each combination *)
 Map[Total, (N[potentialOrders] /. lengthPriceAssociation), {2}];
 (* 72, 72, ... , 95 *)
```

So the worst choice would lead to 95€, the optimal choices lead to 72€.

Ok, but what if I have a few thousands of boards to buy? The above approach is very inefficient and unusable for even a few dozens of boards.

Comment: Look up [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and its [continuous version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem), the linear cutting stock problem, or the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). These are hard problems with great practical implications for which brute force approaches are typically intractable. Clever approximation algorithms have been devised but, as far as I know, these do not guarantee an optimal solution.

Answer (score 7):

(Solution to original problem further below)

MarcoB indicated useful keywords in his comment, in particular this problem is a subclass of the [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem).

For the reference, two links that I did not use directly:

- http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2010/07/multiple-length-cutting-stock-problem.html
- an interesting result: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bin-PackingProblem.html.

Since, as formulated in the OP, it is a difficult mathematical problem with probably no guaranted optimal solution, I (for now) raised the constraint that there are different lengths and costs. I believe the following can be adapted to deal with the original problem, but I am not sure yet.

I will illustrate the answer on the following example, starting from the result: *I will buy 5 boards, cut 1 in 2m + 2m, 1 in 1m+1m+1m+1m, 1 in 1m + 3m, 1 in 3.9m and 1 in 4m.*

Accordingly, the desired order is (units in mm to make avoid confusion between quantities and lengths):

```
order = {{5, 1000}, {2, 2000}, {1, 3000}, {1, 3900}, {1, 4000}};
```

The key idea is to "preprocess" the cutting combinations:

```
lengths = order[[All, 2]];
maxWaste = 0.2;
maxLength = 4000;
possibleQuantities = Table[Range[0, Floor[maxLength/lengths[[i]]]], {i, Length@lengths}];
possibleConfigurations = Select[Tuples[possibleQuantities], 
   (1 - maxWaste)*maxLength <= Total[lengths*#] <= maxLength &];
possibleCuts = SortBy[possibleConfigurations, maxLength - Total[lengths*#] &]
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0, 
    0}, {4, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}} *)
```

For instance, `{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}` means that one 4m board can be cut into 1x1000mm + 1x3000mm. `{0, 0, 0, 1, 0}` means one 4m board can be cut to 1x3900mm. The `maxWaste` parameter was meant to help the optimization by rejecting the bad cutting choices, such as wasting 3m when keeping 1m. But it can be chosen as 1 (i.e. 100%).

Then, the problem is reduced to *finding the number of the different combination cuts so that the number of boards is minimal, under the constraint that the order is filled*:

```
cost[weights_] := Total[weights]
vars = Table[a[i], {i, Length@possibleCuts}];
cons = Thread[Total[vars*possibleCuts] - quantities >= 0]~
   Join~{Thread[vars \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers]};
sol = LinearOptimization[cost[vars], cons, vars];
(* {a[1] -> 1, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 1, a[4] -> 2, a[5] -> 0, a[6] -> 1} *)
```

**Interpretation** The first configuration `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}` is to be chosen `a[1]`, which is the 1x4m board. The fourth configuration `{2, 1, 0, 0, 0}` (2 times 1m and 1 time 2m) is to be chosen a[4] times (= twice).

This uses 5 boards as expected:

```
cost[vars /. sol] 
(* 5 *)
```

Tried on few thousand samples (e.g. `order = {{186, 700}, {182, 750}, {178, 1250}, {121, 2000}, {89, 2150}, {229,  2500}, {89, 2850}, {112, 3000}, {43, 3060}}`), runs instantly.

## Solution to the OP

The above solution can be adapted to deal with multiple stock lengths and prices.

```
displaySol[list_, availableLengths_] := Column@Table[Block[{},
    j = list[[i, 1]];
    number = list[[i, 2]];
    cutconfig = list[[i, 3]];
    correspondingLengths = 
     lengths[[Flatten@Position[list[[i, 2]], _?(# > 0 &)]]];
    listsubdivisions = 
     Flatten@Table[
       lengths[[q]], {q, Length@cutconfig}, {p, cutconfig[[q]]}];
    "Cut " <> ToString[list[[i, 2]]] <> " boards of " <> 
     ToString[availableLengths[[j]]/1000] <> "m into " <> 
     StringRiffle[listsubdivisions, "mm + "] <> "mm (loss = " <> 
     ToString[availableLengths[[j]] - Total@listsubdivisions] <> "mm)"
    ], {i, Length@list}]

computeOptimal[order_, availableLengths_, prices_] := Block[{},
  quantities = order[[All, 1]];
  lengths = order[[All, 2]];
  maxLength = Max@availableLengths;
  possibleQuantities = 
   Table[Range[0, Floor[availableLengths[[j]]/lengths[[i]]]], {j, 
     Length@availableLengths}, {i, Length@lengths}];
  possibleConfigurations = 
   Table[Select[Tuples[possibleQuantities[[i]]], 
     0 <= Total[lengths*#] <= availableLengths[[i]] &], {i, 
     Length@availableLengths}];
  possibleCuts = 
   Table[SortBy[possibleConfigurations[[i]], 
     availableLengths[[i]] - Total[lengths*#] &], {i, 
     Length@availableLengths}];
  vars = Table[
    a[j][i], {j, Length@availableLengths}, {i, 
     Length@possibleCuts[[j]]}];
  cost[vars_] := 
   Table[Total[
      ConstantArray[prices[[i]], Length@possibleCuts[[i]]]*
       vars[[i]]], {i, Length@availableLengths}] // Total;
  cons = Thread[
     Total[Table[
         Total[vars[[j]]*possibleCuts[[j]]], {j, 
          Length@availableLengths}]] - quantities >= 0]~
    Join~{Thread[vars \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers]};
  vars2 = Flatten@vars;
  sol = LinearOptimization[cost[vars], cons, vars2];
  list = Flatten[
    Table[Select[
      Table[{j, a[j][i] /. sol, possibleCuts[[j, i]]}, {i, 
        Length@possibleCuts[[j]]}], #[[2]] > 0 &], {j, 
      Length@availableLengths}], 1];
  Print["You need :" <> 
    StringJoin@
     Table["\n - " <> ToString@quantities[[i]] <> " pieces of " <> 
       ToString@lengths[[i]] <> " mm", {i, Length@order}]];
  Print@displaySol[list, availableLengths];
  Print["Total cost: " <> ToString@cost[vars /. sol]];]
```

Example:

order = {{275, 500}, {186, 700}, {182, 750}, {178, 1250}, {89,
2150}, {57, 2300}, {178, 2500}, {159, 2750}, {145, 2800}, {89,
2850}, {75, 3000}};

`computeOptimal[order, {3000, 4000}, {3, 4}]` returns:

> You need :
>
> - 275 pieces of 500 mm
> - 186 pieces of 700 mm
> - 182 pieces of 750 mm
> - 178 pieces of 1250 mm
> - 89 pieces of 2150 mm
> - 57 pieces of 2300 mm
> - 178 pieces of 2500 mm
> - 159 pieces of 2750 mm
> - 145 pieces of 2800 mm
> - 89 pieces of 2850 mm
> - 75 pieces of 3000 mm

> - Cut 75 boards of 3m into 3000mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 57 boards of 3m into 700mm + 2300mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 122 boards of 3m into 500mm + 2500mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 67 boards of 3m into 750mm + 2150mm (loss = 100mm)
> - Cut 89 boards of 3m into 2850mm (loss = 150mm)
> - Cut 16 boards of 3m into 2800mm (loss = 200mm)
> - Cut 156 boards of 4m into 1250mm + 2750mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 56 boards of 4m into 750mm + 750mm + 2500mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 3 boards of 4m into 500mm + 750mm + 2750mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 129 boards of 4m into 500mm + 700mm + 2800mm (loss = 0mm)
> - Cut 22 boards of 4m into 500mm + 1250mm + 2150mm (loss = 100mm)
>
> Total cost: 2742